# using dictionary in pycuda

Tags: python, cuda, pycuda

I have a dictionary and i would like to know if is it possible to use it as a parameter of a kernel.

for instance

i have the cuda kernel signature

```
__global__ void calTab(Tableaux)
```

Tableaux is a C structure corresponding to

```
typedef struct
{
    float *Tab1;
    float *Tab2;
} Tableaux;
```

in  python Tableaux correspond to the dictionary below:

```
Tableaux={}
Tableaux["Tab1"]=[]
Tableaux["Tab2"]=[]
```

is it possible to use the dictionary as the C structure without using a C API?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of what you are proposing is possible. In PyCUDA, you cannot

1. Pass a dictionary to a kernel
2. Pass a list to a kernel
3. Directly translate a dictionary to C++ structure in device code
4. Directly translate a list to a C++ linear array in device

PyCUDA can use Python classes as C++ structures and it has a numpy like array for use on the GPU. So points 3 and 4 are possible, but not as you would like to do them. Both techniques are discussed in the documentation,[here for gpuarray](http://documen.tician.de/pycuda/array.html) and [here for structures](http://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Examples/DemoStruct).

Comment: hi, thanks for the help but where can i find the appropriate documentation??

Comment: @SOCKet: See the links in my edit. It would be good if you accept this answer just to get this question off the unanswered queue and to make it easier to find in search for the next person that comes along with a similar question